# Does this show the norm of this operator is zero?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces

We have  $$T: C[-1,1]:\to \mathbb{R}$$
$$T(f)=\int_{-1}^1 x f(x) dx$$

The norm considered in $C[-1,1]$ is $$||f||=\max_{x\in[-1,1]} |f(x)|$$

So using $$||T||=\inf\{M:||Tf||\leq M||f||\}$$
in this case we have 
$$|Tf|=|\int_{-1}^1 x f(x)dx|\leq\max_{x\in[-1,1]}|f(x)||\int_{-1}^1x dx|=||f|||\int_{-1}^1x dx|$$

but $$|\int_{-1}^1x dx|=0$$

so can we say that the norm is 0? since always $||T||\geq 0$

Comment: I think I did it wrong, $|Tf|\leq  ||f||1$ so the norm should be $\leq1$. Now need a $f$ with $||f||\leq 1$ and $|Tf|=1$

Comment: The first step of your inequality is not correct.  It is generally not true that $|\int_{-1}^1 xf(x)dx| \leq \|f\|_{\infty}|\int_{-1}^1 xdx|$.  For instance, that result is clearly false for the function $f(x) = x$.

Answer (score 3):

The norm of your $T$ is one. Indeed, you have
$$
|Tf|=\left|\int_{-1}^1\,xf(x)\,dx\right|\leq\int_{-1}^1|x|\,|f(x)|\,dx\leq\|f\|\,\int_{-1}^1|x|\,dx=\|f\|
$$
(note that when you did this inequality in your question, you missed the absolute value on $x$).
This shows that $\|T\|\leq1$. Now let 
$$
f_n(t)=\begin{cases}-1,&\ -1\leq t\leq -\frac1n\\ \\ nt,&\ -\frac1n<t<\frac1n\\ \\1,&\ \frac1n\leq t\leq1 \end{cases}
$$
Then $\|f_n\|=1$, and 
$$
|Tf_n|=2\int_0^{1/n}nx\,dx+2\int_{1/n}^1x\,dx=\frac1n+\left(1-\frac1n\right)^2=1-\frac{n-1}{n^2}.
$$
By choosing $n$ big enough we can get $|Tf_n|$ are near one as we want, so $\|T\|=1$.